# How to call a simplicial set where every boundary of a simplex can be filled?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, at.algebraic-topology, terminology

What is the correct terminology for the following property of a simplicial set $X_\bullet$:

> For every $k\geq 0$, every map $\partial\Delta^k\to X_\bullet$ can be extended to a map $\Delta^k\to X_\bullet$.

Comment: what about "flag"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a contractible Kan complex.  It's equivalent to the same condition where you replace the pairs $(\Delta^k,\partial\Delta^k)$ with *all* pairs $(A,B)$ where $B\subset A$, since $A$ can be built from $B$ by iteratively filling in simplices whose boundaries are already filled in.  In particular, any such $X$ will satisfy the Kan condition, and applying the condition to the pair $(X\times \Delta^1, X\times\partial\Delta^1)$ gives a contraction of $X$.

Conversely, given a contractible Kan complex $X$ and a map $\partial \Delta^k\to X$, by contractibility it extends over the cone on $\partial\Delta^k$.  But that cone is just a $(k+1)$-horn, and filling in the horn gives a $k$-simplex in $X$ extending the original map.